# QProcess: память и время

Tags: qt, c++

Имеется цикл, перебирающий тучу строк (более 100000). Для каждой строки вызывается функция:

```
for (QList<QString>::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
    Checker::CheckIt((*i));

Checker::CheckIt(QString str) 
{
    check.start("addToCheckList " + str);
    check.waitForFinished();
    check.close();
    check.kill();
}
```

Занимает эта операции таки не мало времени, несколько минут.

Каким образом лучше реализовать подобное и как можно ускорить процесс обработки? Создовать новый объект для каждой команды `QProcess command = new QProcess();`? Тогда как его удалять из памяти после завершения?

Comment: Если Вы будете создавать объекты на каждый чих, то вряд ли что то ускорите. Хотите ускорить - ускоряйте addToCheckList. Если эта программа не работает быстро, то оптимизировать QProcess нет смысла.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне не нужен ответ от нее, а лишь отправить команду и забить.

Comment: Используйте QProcess::startDetached(): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached

Comment: Попробуйте распараллелить через openMP, чтобы задействовать все ядра.
Если речь идет об обработке более чем 100 000 элементов, каждая из которых занимает ядро на пару минут, разумно распараллелить процесс обработки между многими машинами. В таком случае очень удобно будет использовать ZeroMQ.

Если же процесс обработки на самом деле не ест процессорное время, а ест только время, например, в ожидании какого-то ответа с какого-то сервера, то разумно увеличивать количество Checker, пока оно будет давать увеличение в скорости, запуская каждый в отдельном потоке.

Comment: На обработку 117000 элементов уходит около 5 минут.
Мне не нужно ждать ответа от выполненной команды.

Comment: При запуске проверьте, что загружаются все ядра машины. Если нет - распараллельте.

Comment: @avengerweb, что именно делают эти команды?

Читают файлы, обмениваются по сети, правят базу данных и т.д.

Могут они при одновременном запуске мешать друг-другу (пересекаются ли по данным)?

Comment: Команды делает проверку и если элемента нет заносит в память, а там уже проводятся иные действия.
Не мешают.

Comment: @avengerweb, понимания, что именно эти команды делают, откровенно говоря, не прибавилось.

Если команды независимы, то распараллеливание должно ускорить обработку, но одновременный запуск 100000 процессов -- это как-то ... (мягко говоря, настораживает).

Вообще-то, если результат команд не интересен и ждать не нужно, то проще всего сгенерить скрипт и запустить его в фоне тем же .start.

Comment: В данном случае она просто исполняет системную команду, которая заносит в приложения строку, занес = отработал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обязательно нужен QProcess? Если нет, то можно через QThread. Например, "разбить" общий контейнер на куски, заданные начальным и конечным итератором. Создать свои объекты-наследники QThread, куда передавать итераторы начала и конца.

```
class MyProc : public QThread
{
...
MyProc(QList<QString>::ConstIterator from, QList<QString>::ConstIterator to);
virtual void run() 
{ 
    for(QList<QString>::ConstIterator it = m_from; it != m_to; ++it)
    {
        Checker::CheckIt(*it);
    }
}
};
```

Вызвать можно примерно так:

```
int part = list.size()/num_of_processes;
if(list.size()%num_of_processes>0) part += 1;
for(QList<QString>::ConstIterator it = list.begin(); 
it !=  list.end(); 
(it + (part+1) < list.end())? (it+=(part+1)) : (it=list.end()) )
{
    QList<QString>::ConstIterator it2 = (it + (part+1) < list.end())? (it+(part+1)) : (list.end());
    MyProc *myproc = new MyProc(it,it2);
    myproc->start();
}
```

В этом наброске конечный итератор to - "не включительный", т.е. следующий за конечным.

В лучшем случае это даст ускорение в количество раз, равное количеству процессоров.

Answer (score 3):

Удалять из памяти по завершению процесса лучше всего так:

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
connect(proc, SIGNAL(finished(int)), proc, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

Такое удаление будет безопасным, и произойдет только когда процесс полностью завершится. При этом вы не забудете очистить память - так как код очистки сразу следует за созданием процесса.